# BeautifulSoup not finding all

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've got the following source code trying to parse a web page however, it appears that it does not find all the instances wherethe class "row dataraekker" appears in

```
cvr = 45963128
url = 'https://datacvr.virk.dk/data/visenhed?enhedstype=virksomhed&id=%s&soeg=%s' % (str(cvr), str(cvr))

rObject = requests.get(url)
html = rObject.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
registerHistoryTab = soup.find('div', class_="accordion ", id="accordion-Historisk")
dataRows = registerHistoryTab.find_all('div', class_='row dataraekker')
print len(dataRows)
```

registerHistoryTab holds **2** items with the following HTML, where multiple div's appear "out of nowhere" as that's not the case in the page's source code

```
<div class="accordion " data-pdf-class="accordion hide accordion-Historisk" id="accordion-Historisk">
<div class="accordion-group accordion-wrapper">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<div>
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_-Historisk">
<h1>Registreringshistorik<div class="text-left help_element help_acc Help-Historisk" data-pdf-class="hide"></div></h1>
</a>
</div>
<!--pdf-linje-->
</div>
<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse_-Historisk">
<div class="accordion-inner" data-pdf-class="sektion">
<div class="aktive-registreringstidende">
<div class="row dataraekker">
<div class="col-sm-12" data-pdf-class="column12">
<b>04.06.2015  Ændring i personkreds</b><br>
<b>CVR-nummer:</b><p>45963128.</p><b>NAVN:</b><p>UNILEVER DANMARK A/S.</p>Adresse: Ørestads Boulevard 73, 2300 København S.<br/>Kommune: København.<br/><b>Bestyrelse:<br/></b><h2>Fratrådte:</h2><p>Jens Christian Voldmester, den 01.06.2015.</p><b>Direktion:<br/></b><h2>Fratrådte:</h2><p>Jens Christian Voldmester, (adm. dir), den 01.06.2015.</p><h2>Tiltrådte:</h2><p>Henrico Drent, (adm. dir), Burgemeester Vogelslaan 63, 5062 KN, Oisterwijk, Holland, den 01.06.2015.</p><hr> </hr></br></div>
</div><div class="row dataraekker">
<div class="col-sm-12" data-pdf-class="column12">
<b>06.03.2015  Øvrige ændringer, Ændring i personkreds</b><br>
<p><b>CVR-nummer: </b>45963128</p><p><b>Navn og adresse: </b></p></br>UNILEVER  DANMARK A/S</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

The issue appears at the find method because registerHistoryTab is not as it is when viewing the web page

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue appears at the find method because registerHistoryTab is not as it is when viewing the web page

Never expect your HTML returned by `requests` be the same as you see in the browser. When you deal with HTML parsing, work with what you've got inside the response and what you see in the browser.

Note that in this case, just switching the parser from `html.parser` to `lxml` solves the problem:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Now I see `64` printed instead of `2`.

Note that this requires `lxml` to be installed: `pip install --upgrade lxml`.

Also see:

- [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: "and what you see in the browser" ... Should that be "and **not** what you see in the browser"?